# Why would an attacker include a request body with an HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, web-scanners

I have a website that does not run PHP (management decision) or has wordpress installed. Intermittently, I receive a few requests for wp_login pages that trip my IDS. The requests are served with a 404 and I am sure they are just a bot looking for WP administrative pages to attack further.
However, in some cases the GET requests are funny because they contain HTML response from some *another* server as body. E.g

```
GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: charitable_session=<SESSID>;wordpressuser_<ID>=+; wordpresspass_<ID>=+; _wp_session=<SESSID>%7C%7C1472773689;
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 35870
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,en-us;q=0.7,es;q=0.3
Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Oops! The page you are looking for does not exist.</title>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="generator" content="Flynax Classifieds Software" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=n

o, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tiruvannamalai.co.in/templates/general_wide/css/style.css" />
```

[This answer of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/533524) says that webserver SHOULD ignore the request body and I am sure my web-server does so.

My question is what possible benefit can somebody derive from such a scan? Is it just a buggy code that pipes response from one scan into another (Seeing that even headers such as `Content-Length` are added to request)?

Comment: If you were to run WordPress, it would have been more difficult to notice this request as a bot, because it mocks Safari quite good. It still doesn't explain why the HTML is send (especially in a GET request). Best guess, some random HTML content is used for fuzz testing.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, possibly caused by poor memory management. I can think of no benefit to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be deliberate, though nothing obvious leaps out from that specific body.

There are techniques like request smuggling that involve subtle protocol violations. See for instance:

http://www.cgisecurity.com/lib/HTTP-Request-Smuggling.pdf

Might be interesting to see if the length of the request body is in fact 35870, or if something interesting appears at that place in the request stream.